# Redistribute columns along x axis using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using this code:

```
ggplot(total_reads, aes(x=Week, y=Reads)) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_log10(breaks=breaks, minor_breaks=minor_breaks) +
    scale_x_continuous() +
    facet_grid(~PEDIS, scales="free_x", space = "free_x") +
    theme_classic() +
    ylab("Total Bacterial Reads")
```

I produced this graph:

[image]

How do I remove the empty spaces in the first facet (pedis1) and make sure only the relevant labels are on the x axis (ie 0,3,6,12,13)?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is because your x axis values (`total_reads$Week`) is an integer/number.  This automatically sets the scale to be continuous and therefore you have spacing according to the distance on the scale (like any numeric scale).  If you want to have the bars right next to one another and remove the white space, you'll need to set the x axis to a discrete variable when plotting.  It's easiest to do this by mapping `factor(Week)` right in the `aes()` declaration.

Here's an example with that modification as well as some other suggestions described below:

```
total_reads <- data.frame(
  Week=c(0,3,6,12,13),
  Reads=c(100,110,100,129,135),
  PEDIS=c(rep('PEDIS1', 3), rep('PEDIS2',2))
)

ggplot(total_reads, aes(x=factor(Week), y=Reads)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~PEDIS, scales="free_x", space="free_x") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

A few other notes on what you see changed here:

- Use `geom_col()`, not `geom_bar()`.  If you [check out the documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html) associated with the `geom_bar()` function, you can see it mentions that `geom_bar()` is used for showing counts of observations along a single axis, whereas if you want to show *value*, you should use `geom_col()`.  You get the same effect with `geom_col()` as if you use `geom_bar(stat="identity")`.
- Remove `scale_x_continuous()`.  Not sure why you have this there anyway, but if your column `Week` is numeric, it would default to use this scale anyway.  If you do use the sale, you will ask `ggplot` to *force* a continuous scale - apparently not what you want here.